# Save data into a text file

Tags: java, file, ioexception, filewriter

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ucet ucet = new Ucet();
        ucet.vlozPenize("100");
        System.out.println(ucet.ziskejPenize());
        ucet.ulozPenize();
    }
}

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Ucet {

    private File file;
    private int penize;

    public Ucet() {
        this.file = new File("ucet.txt");
        this.penize = 0;
    }

    public void ulozPenize() {
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            fileWriter.write(penize);
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void vlozPenize(int penize) {
        this.penize += penize;
    }

    public int ziskejPenize() {
        return this.penize;
    }
}
```

When I start this code normally you think it will put a "100" into the text file, but it inputs a "d" like a char. Anyone know how to fix that? One method should input a data, one should enter that data and one should save that data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write the text representation of 100 to your file, you need to do the following

```
private Integer penize;
```

Then in the write method of the `FileWritter`

```
fileWriter.write(penize.toString());
```

The reason was because you cannot pass numbers as an argument in `write` method you have to use `String`

Comment: or just use String.valueOf(penize) in the write method instead of changing from int to Integer, because that makes a bit more sense, but yes this would work